# keyup to ignore ctrl+a (select all)

Tags: jquery

I have a text box which I want to automatically call a function when something is entered inside. I have that working with the following script but there is one annoying thing.
In the textbox if i do select all (ctrl+a) it also calls the function. Is it possible to modify the below script to do nothing when ctrl+a is detected ? how can i achieve this?

i've tried using keydown, keypress but they don't ignore it but I found keyup works best with my application.

```
    $("#someid").keyup(
        function () {
            callfunction();
        }
    );
```

Comment: this will automatically unblock the texts after it is blocked. cannot find any better solution yet. http://jsfiddle.net/6775s7qh/

Comment: thank you for the solution - it works but found Abhishek's solution below more simpler to implement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following code.

```
    $("#someid").on('input', function(){
            callfunction();
        });
```

Comment: Worked for me too